# Cmake not adding library search path

Tags: path, linker, cmake

I'm currently changing one of my projects to cmake for portably. Within the project directory I have a folder with an external library called **"boclib"**, which is build by a regular makefile. I need to link my executable to **"ProjectDir"/boclib/bin/libboc.a** .  My current attempt looks like this:

```
  FIND_LIBRARY(BOCLIB boc ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/boclib/bin)
  Message(${BOCLIB})
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(prod ${BOCLIB})
```

The Meassage output yields the correct library:

```
"AbsulutePathToProjectDir"/boclib/bin/libboc.a
```

Which outputs this, when linking:

```
g++ -lm -ldl CMakeFiles/prod.dir/src/BocData.cpp.o CMakeFiles/prod.dir/src/delay.cpp.o     CMakeFiles/prod.dir/src/leoni.cpp.o CMakeFiles/prod.dir/src/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/prod.dir/src/scope.cpp.o CMakeFiles/prod.dir/src/SerialCom.cpp.o CMakeFiles/prod.dir/src/tester.cpp.o CMakeFiles/prod.dir/src/Utils.cpp.o  -o prod  boclib/bin/libboc.a -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_serialization -lboc
```

There is no -L option for the boclib. 
What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it actually fail to link?

Comment: yes it does. the g++ command I posted gives me ld: library not found for -lboc", because it doesn't find the lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's two occurence of "boc" library in the g++ command you pasted, the first: `boclib/bin/libboc.a` that should comes from your target_link_libraries call and a second one: `-lboc` that must come from something else in your CMakeLists.txt.

You don't need that second one, if you find why it's added and remove it, it should be ok.